# Access the observable from inside a template

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have this code:

```
<div class="yui3-u-4-5" data-bind="template:{name:'datetimepickertpl', data: r.startDateTime }"></div>
```

This renders a template which utilises a date and time picker.  However, what's important to know is that I'm extenders on my observables to augment their functionality. On this startDateTime observable I have an extended property called "date".

So inside the template I do this (I have simplified the code for demo)

```
<span data-bind="html: date"></span>
```

However, the date member cannot be found.

I know *why* this is. It's because the template binding unwraps the observable when it sets it as the binding context for the template.  So it's looking effectively for startDateTime().date rather than startDateTime.date.

So does anyone know how I can access the observable object inside template and *not* the contents of the observable?

I can always wrap the observable like this:

```
<div class="yui3-u-4-5" data-bind="template:{name:'datetimepickertpl', data: { ob: r.startDateTime } }"></div>
```

and then do reference ob.date, however, this is a little messy.

thanks for your help

kris

Comment: Wrapping the object is the general solution to this type of issue. If you prefer not to wrap it in the binding string, then you would want to look at structuring your view model in a way that you could pass an object that contains your observable as a property directly.

Comment: ok thanks! don't you just love knockout? You know Steve is from my hometown #veryproud